# CSS media query operators

Tags: css, media-queries, terminology

Can some one explain to me in very simple terms what the operators `and`, `not`, `only` and the comma `,` mean and do in CSS?

Comment: What do you not understand about what the spec says?

Comment: That's not very helpful.

Comment: I don't know how my question can be anymore helpful it states what I'm having trouble with.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/media_queries

Answer (score 1):

The four operators implement set theory logic. In that context, here is what each one means:

- `,`: equivalent of 'union'; e.g. `@media screen, print` matches a screen or print device
- `and`: equivalent of 'intersection'; e.g. `@media screen and (min-device-width: 1920px)` matches a screen device with 1920px resolution
- `not`: equivalent of 'set difference'; e.g. `@media not screen and (color)` matches a device which is not a screen and supports color
- `only`: equivalent of a 'proper superset'; e.g. `@media only screen and (color)` matches a device which is only a screen and only supports color

**References**

- [Nesting media queries | The Haystack](http://www.the-haystack.com/2012/10/17/nesting-media-queries/)
- [Logic in Media Queries | CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/logic-in-media-queries/)
- [Media Queries Level 4: Evaluating Media Queries](https://www.w3.org/TR/mediaqueries-4/#evaluating)