# CSS @media query multiple sets of logical operators (and/or)

Tags: css, media-queries

In CSS, I would like to have some rules that apply if either the page is between 600px and 750px wide, or if the page is wider than 1200px.

I know that there are [many operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787287/css-media-query-operators), but I am stuck trying to use multiple of them together. Here's what I've tried so far, which works in Firefox, but not Chrome, and VS Code underlines this in red:

```
@media ((min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 750px)) or (min-width: 1200px) {
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Did your read the answer at your link? "`,`: equivalent of 'union'; e.g. `@media screen, print` matches a screen **or** print device". And no need for first group parentheses.

Comment: Is there a generic solution to this problem? What if I wanted to have a more complex operation?

Comment: Like what more complex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always use [Bootstrap Grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/#grid-options) system that save tons of time. There's also [Flex from Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/flex/) that is a no brainer when it comes to responsiveness. You basically put the class d-flex to mostly everything and it'll resize automatically.